Solve $x\frac{dy}{dx}-2x(x-y)=y$ for the domain all real $x$
I wanted to solve the differential equation (DE) $$x\frac{dy}{dx}-2x(x-y)=y$$ for the domain $x\in\mathbb{R}$. However, the choice of substitution given to me $y=xt$ requires the condition that $x\neq 0$. The following is my attempt to solve the given DE.
\begin{split}
& x\frac{dy}{dx}-2x(x-y)=y \\
\iff & x(x\frac{dt}{dx}+t)-2x(x-xt)=xt \\
\iff & x^2\frac{dt}{dx}+xt-2x^2+2x^2t=xt \\
\iff & x^2\frac{dt}{dx}-2x^2+2x^2t=0 \\
\iff & \frac{dt}{dx}=2-2t~\text{because}~x\neq0\\
\iff & \int{\frac{1}{1-t}~dt}=\int{2~dx} \\
\iff & -\ln|1-t|=2x+C \\
\iff & \ln|1-t|=e^{-C}e^{-2x} \\
\iff & 1-t=\pm e^{-C}e^{-2x} \\
\iff & 1-t=Ae^{-2x},~\text{where}~A=\pm e^{-C} \\
\iff & 1-\frac{y}{x}=Ae^{-2x} \\
\iff & y=x(1-Ae^{-2x}). \\
\end{split}
I noticed that $y=x(1-Ae^{-2x})$ does satisfy the given DE over all real $x$, so I was hoping to get some advice on how to solve this DE over all real $x$ instead of over $n\neq 0$.

Use smoothness assumptions to deal with the case $x=0$ the constant may not be the same on the right as on the left also $y(0)=0$

The substitution $ y = x t $ excludes $ x = 0 $ due to division by $ x $, but the derived solution $ y = x(1 - A e^{-2x}) $ satisfies the differential equation for all $ x \in \mathbb{R} $, including $ x = 0 $, where it simplifies to $ y = 0 $.

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}+ y \left(2-\dfrac{1}{x} \right) = 2x$. Thats the linear form.
